# Limit string size RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match all the expressions where the string length is greater than 1. This is my regex.

```
string.match(/\B\w+(?=\w)/gi);
```

I tried with this:

```
string.match(/^\B\w+(?=\w){2,}$/gi);
```

But it doesn't work...

Comment: Ermmm... `string.length > 1`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match every word longer than **one** character - use the *quantifier* - `\w{2,}`.

```js
var str = "a b cd efg hijk",
    res = str.match(/\w{2,}/g);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Another possible solution would be *splitting* the array and filtering out every word longer than **one** character.

```js
var str = "a b cd efg hijk",
    res = str.split(' ').filter(v => v.length > 1);
    
    console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Any string with length more than 1.

```
.{2,}
```

Test it on https://regex101.com/

Comment: Anything more than two length is moot, so  `.{2}` is all that's needed.

Comment: @Kinduser - what do you mean?

Comment: @sln The *comma* is obligatory in this case. OP wants to match every word longer than two characters. Using this regex without that sign, will return even amount of characters from every word.

Comment: @Kinduser  - I don't know about the  OP question, he states any string longer that 2 characters, meaning string.length() > 1. So, the un-needed regex version is `.{2}` Not really sure if it's word qualified, or even if he wants to match a word at all. And it's a single regex test, not really a findall or match all kind of thing.

Comment: @sln He has accepted my answer so it seems like it's all about the words (:

Comment: Go figure .. I guess so.